# Android - Check if activity is open for the first time

Tags: java, android

Before people say this is a duplicate of "check if android is on first run", this question is to check if the activity itself (not the app in whole) is open for the first time.

I have different activities that run Material Tap Target Prompt, so a few pop-ups that explain the buttons and functions.
But I only want it to run for first time users.

Now I tried the following:

```
        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstRun",false).apply();
                 ........Do the pop ups
}
```

But this will set it for the whole app and so when the user gets to the next screen it won't run because the boolean is set to false.

So I am trying to find a way to check if the activity itself is opened for the first time but I can't seem to find anything that would solve this issue.

I thought about using a variable then setting it to 1. But if the users restarts the app, it crashes etc then that var will be reset.

May other option is to create a row in a DB and then check if that is set to 1 or whatever depending on the activity.

But maybe there is an easier way?

Thank you

Comment: Just create different keys for each activity - "firstRunActivity1", "firstRunActivity2", etc.

Comment: you can try to use as key - `MyActivity.class.getSimpleName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just create preference keys for each Activity. Sample code added below:

```
if (prefs.getBoolean(MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName(), true)) {
           prefs.edit().putBoolean(MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName(),false).apply();
                 ........Do the pop-ups
}
```

Comment: because I did not know you could do this. WIll give this and go. Thanks!

Comment: @vizsatiz What is `prefs` ?

Comment: preference keys. Sorry for the late reply